# Hartl Tutorial Setup: trouble with gem configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been trying to figure this out for entirely too long now.  I'm using the [Hartl RoR Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book?version=3.2#sec%3ainstall_git) and trying to get all of the programs set up.

I'm trying to set up the gem that will allow me to open a file directly in Sublime Text 2 from the terminal.  Unfortunately, because I am a noob, I can't post pictures here.  However, if you search for "listing 1.1" this is the area I am confused with.

I keep getting error messages like these:

```
Jonathans-MacBook-Air:~ jbh5079$ subl ~/.gemrc
-bash: subl: command not found

Jonathans-MacBook-Air:~ jbh5079$ ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl
ln: /Users/jbh5079/bin/subl: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a rails problem - it's a command line / bash problem, the command subl cannot be found. For a tutorial for setting this up, google "mac starting sublime from command line"
which yields

https://gist.github.com/1195304

among others.